# Php Unlink Button For Each Link

Tags: php, html

I want to put delete button for each link.Links are from directory
This button is going to should delete these file but i stuck there.This is my code

```
echo '<a target="_blank" href="'.$dir.$file.'">'.$file.'</a><button>AA</button><br>'."\n";
```

Comment: At the moment your button does nothing, but the link next to it does. Is that your intention?

Comment: This is code is somewhere else.I just modified it.I realized and change it but  I coldn't find putting button for opposite of links to remove them with mkdir

Answer (score 1):

You could call a server side function (ajax or post) that takes $dir and $file and deletes the file off the server

Comment: ...with the necessary validation and precautions, so that the user can't delete `/etc/passwd` or `C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll`

Comment: and also some token system in order to prevent CSRF attacks